# How to safeguard a different token stored in an ERC20 contract from unwanted withdrawal?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20

If I want to store say a popular ERC20 (e.g. BNB) in my new ERC20 contract, how do I prevent someone from making unauthorized withdrawal of these BNBs from my contract account ? Is it possible that a person can obtain the address of my contract, invoke an instance of BNB ERC20 contract and initiate a transfer of these BNBs to their account ?

Comment: Have you considered searching for an example implementation of ERC20 and see what's in there? You would have seen that it's all taken care of in any decent implementation (probably in any implementation that you could find, since why would anyone implement an ERC20 token contract without it???). Here is an example of [the most commonly used one](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) by OpenZeppelin.

Comment: @goodvibration Let's say if you want to store some BNBs in BAT's contract. Will safeguards in BAT's contract be also applicable on BNB ?

Answer (score 1):

Each token has exactly one token contract which acts as the token ledger. A token contract is typically for just keeping track of that one token - who owns and how many of said token.

A token contract typically cannot manage other tokens. In theory you can add such functionality into one but it would not be a very good idea. If you want to have some way to manage multiple different tokens you should create a new contract for handling them - or even just simply use a regular wallet.

However anyone *can* transfer any token to any token contract but after that the contract can't transfer the token onwards so the token is essentially burned.

So you shouldn't worry about multiple tokens in a single token contract because that just doesn't happen. And if it does the tokens are quite safe there as nobody can transfer them out of there anymore.